# Problems on Casting with an Insert Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Good morning. Trying to get the following query to CSV load data through a statement and failing miserably any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my data:

[image: data]

The statement that I'm using is:

```
create table #tempTablea 
(
Employee_Id nvarchar(50), 
First_Name nvarchar(50), 
Last_Name nvarchar(50), 
Japanese_Staff nvarchar(50), 
Worker_Type nvarchar(50), 
Hourly___Salaried nvarchar(50), 
[Date] nvarchar(50), 
[Start] nvarchar(50), 
[End] nvarchar(50), 
[Hour] nvarchar(50), 
Timesheet_Start nvarchar(50), 
Timesheet_End nvarchar(50),
Note nvarchar(50), 
Is_Time_Off nvarchar(50),
Department_Full_Path nvarchar(50),
Called_In_Full_Path nvarchar(50),
Time_Off_Name nvarchar(50))

BULK INSERT #tempTablea FROM 'c:\data\555.csv' WITH
(

FIRSTROW = 8,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
ERRORFILE = 'C:\Errors\Error.CSV',TABLOCK)


INSERT INTO Ignition.dbo.timelogtest
(Employee_Id,
First_Name,
Last_Name,
Japanese_Staff,
Worker_Type,
[Date],
[Start],
[End],
[Hourly___Salaried],
[Hour],
Timesheet_Start,
Timesheet_End,
Note,
Is_Time_Off,
Department_Full_Path,
Called_In_Full_Path,
Time_Off_Name)
    select t.Employee_Id,t.First_Name,t.Last_Name,t.Japanese_Staff,t.Worker_Type,t.Hourly___Salaried,(Cast(t.[Date] as date)),(Cast(t.[Start] as datetime)), (Cast(t.[End] as datetime)),t.[Hour],(Cast(t.Timesheet_Start as date)), (CAST(t.Timesheet_End as date)), t.Note,t.Is_Time_Off,t.Department_Full_Path,t.Called_In_Full_Path,Time_Off_Name
    from #tempTablea t
```

The error that I get is:

> (815 rows affected) Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 30 Conversion
>   failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

So I know the data is loading into the temp table but when I load that data into the actual table I want it in it's failing, I'm assuming it's on the cast from the dates but not sure how I'm doing it wrong. I would do flat file except I'll receive this CSV every day and I want to just set it to eventually be automated where it just picks up the CSV and runs it daily with no one interacting with it. If you could help me with getting it from the temp table into the actual table I would be much obliged thanks!

Comment: try deleting line 30 and try again? check if line30 values are different from any other line

Comment: The problem is in the conversion of your csv data. In your temp table all columns are nvarchar(50) so it accept any string. You target table has some Date, DateTime, Time (you didn't provide the table definition, so it is just guess) columns. If you look at the data - "-" is not a valid value for Time or DateTime; Your Date column might contain date in a wrong format (some data hidden by ###). You should fix your input data for correctness or handle conversion in your code.

Comment: Gotcha - Unfortunately this is sent to us from a 3rd party who keeps up with our production hours for us and that's the only report they can give to us. I may have to go back and request formatting on their side it appears?

Comment: Perhaps the `-` character means null?

Comment: what version of sql server

Answer (score 0):

In your INSERT..SELECT, replace all of your `CAST` and `CONVERT` statements with `TRY_CAST` and `TRY_CONVERT`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be tacky but I figured it out due to being convert instead of cast. Posting answer in case anyone else has issues further along - Thank you all for input I appreciate.

```
   if object_id('tempdb..#tempTablea') is not null
    drop table #tempTablea
    create table #tempTablea 
    (
    Employee_Id nvarchar(50), 
    First_Name nvarchar(50), 
    Last_Name nvarchar(50), 
    Worker_Type nvarchar(50), 
    [Date] nvarchar(50), 
    [Start] nvarchar(50), 
    [End] nvarchar(50), 
    [Hour] nvarchar(50), 
    Is_Time_Off nvarchar(50),
    Department_Full_Path nvarchar(50),
    Time_Off_Name varchar(75))

    BULK INSERT #tempTablea FROM 'c:Data\555.csv' WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 9,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\Errors\Error.CSV',TABLOCK)

    INSERT INTO Ignition.dbo.timelogtest
    (Employee_Id,
    First_Name,
    Last_Name,
    Worker_Type,
    [Date],
    [Start],
    [End],
    [Hour],
    Is_Time_Off,
    Department_Full_Path,
    Time_Off_Name)

        select t.Employee_Id,t.First_Name,t.Last_Name,t.Worker_Type,
        convert(date,t.[date]),convert(datetime2,t.[Start]),Convert(datetime2,t.[End]),t.[Hour], t.Is_Time_Off,
        t.Department_Full_Path,t.Time_Off_Name
        from #tempTablea t
        where t.[date] not in (select [date] from Ignition.dbo.timelogtest)
```